# How to edit my answers?

Tags: support, editing

I'm new here and I'm having some problems to edit my answers. I don't know how to edit them. So I'm forced to answer the question with my iPhone keyboard. Can someone suggest something?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding what you are asking.  How does not knowing how to edit your answers force you to answer with an "iPhone keyboard"?  It is possible to answer and edit posts with a smartphone, though I find it awkward in comparison to using a laptop or desktop keyboard.

Comment: @hardmath I'm simply asking how to edit my answers on my phone ( without app )

Comment: When you view your posts in a browser, there is an Edit button (link) under the post  (between Favorite and Share in the mobile version of the site).

Comment: @hardmath how can I add all the symbols and formulas on my browser . How can I edit using MathJax ?

Comment: If you have familiarity with $\LaTeX$ already, this [introduction to MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) should get you started.  It has links to more advanced techniques.

Comment: @hardmath I'm not familiar with $\LaTeX$

Comment: Then that's a bit of a learning curve.  You can probably find examples of what you would like to imitate by browsing previous Questions and Answers and looking at their Edit histories.  However cutting-and-pasting with a smartphone is fairly tedious and error prone, in my experience.